# How To Get Current Logged In User in CookieAuthenticationEvents (.Net Core 3.1)

Tags: cookies, asp.net-core-identity, .net-core-3.1

This is a web application developed using .net core 3.1. 
I want to record user and its log out time upon cookies expiration. 
The code below will be executed every time Identity.Application cookies expires,

```
public class CustomCookieAuthenticationEvents : CookieAuthenticationEvents
{
    private readonly ApplicationDbContext context;
    private readonly IHttpContextAccessor accessor;

    public CustomCookieAuthenticationEvents(ApplicationDbContext context, IHttpContextAccessor accessor)
    {
        this.context = context;
        this.accessor = accessor;
    }

    public override async Task RedirectToLogin(RedirectContext<CookieAuthenticationOptions> redirectContext)
    {
        var username = accessor.HttpContext.User.Identity.Name; // username always null
        var datetime = DateTime.Now;

        /*
            insert data into database table
        */

        redirectContext.Response.Redirect(redirectContext.RedirectUri);
        await Task.FromResult(0);
    }
}
```

This is my startup,

```
// Set identity path and idle time
services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(options =>
{
    options.AccessDeniedPath = "/Identity/Account/AccessDenied";
    options.LoginPath = "/Identity/Account/Login";
    options.LogoutPath = "/Identity/Account/Logout";
    options.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5);
    options.SlidingExpiration = true;
    options.EventsType = typeof(CustomCookieAuthenticationEvents);
});

// custom auto logout event handler
services.AddScoped<CustomCookieAuthenticationEvents>();
```

Everything is working well except the **username** variable always null. 
I think I'm missing something here, any help would be appreciated!

Comment: The `RedirectToLogin()` method is called when the current user is not signed in. So I assume there's no User ?

Comment: @itminus only `RedirectToLogin()` method is being called when cookies expires, the others event will not be executed, do you have any work-around?

Answer (score 0):

First, register `CustomCookieAuthenticationEvents` as scoped:

```
services.AddScoped<CustomCookieAuthenticationEvents>();
```

then, instead of

```
var username = accessor.HttpContext.User.Identity.Name;
```

use

```
var username = context.Principal.Identity.Name;
```